# class factory using a list of types and polymorphism of statics

Tags: c#, .net, types, polymorphism

I am trying to create a class factory that uses a list of class types, calls overridden methods to find the class that matches the criteria, and then returns an instance of the "matched" class.  I am currently doing it with a list of class instances, which is ok, but using types would seem cleaner.  Otherwise we need to reinitialize the instance every time we actually use the class to "clean up" the internal working variables.  Does polymorphism work with static methods and types?  I frequently use polymorphism, but have not thought about approaching it this way before.

My simplified current code is like this:

```
public static List<RatingEngineBase> RatingEngineList = new List<RatingEngineBase>();
RatingEngineList.Add(new RE_PPL_DTNA_Cleveland_ATT());
RatingEngineList.Add(new RE_PPL_DTNA_Cleveland_Coldiron());
RatingEngineList.Add(new RE_PPL_DTNA_Cleveland_Prestige());
RatingEngineList.Add(new RE_PPL_DTNA_MtHolly_ATT());
foreach(RatingEngineBase RatingEngine in RatingEngineList)
{
    if (RatingEngine.OrderItemToRatePathMatch(anOrderItemToRate))
    {
        RatingEngine.OrderItemToRate = anOrderItemToRate;
        return RatingEngine;
    }
}
```

But I think it would be cleaner if I could do something like:

```
public static List<typeof(RatingEngineBase)> RatingEngineTypeList = new List<typeof(RatingEngineBase));
RatingEngineTypeList.Add(typeof(RE_PPL_DTNA_Cleveland_ATT));
RatingEngineTypeList.Add(typeof(RE_PPL_DTNA_Cleveland_Coldiron));
RatingEngineTypeList.Add(typeof(RE_PPL_DTNA_Cleveland_Prestige));
RatingEngineTypeList.Add(typeof(RE_PPL_DTNA_MtHolly_ATT));
```

And then iterate through the list of types, call the overridden static OrderItemToRatePathMatch, and then create and return the instance of the matching one.

Hopefully this helps explain my question.

Comment: Sure you can use a list of types, and yes you can try to cast/convert using static types.  What _specifically_ are you stuck on?  A code sample would be more helpful that describing what you've tried and what you want.

Comment: I guess what OP is essentially asking is will polymorphism work with static methods\classes?Answer to the question is No. Ofcourse, OP can post code sample which can help us to give alternate solution.

Comment: The only time I ever attempted something like this it was for a really bad optimization that wasn't really needed. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: It seems like it would be a cleaner approach, but like @AlexKrups said, it is not something I have tried or even really thought through before.  The current approach seems a little weak since I am using an instance of each class to call a static method to see if it matches.  I wanted to get opinions from other seasoned developers.